# How does another program/process interrupt the execution of my program?

Tags: user-interface, callback, interrupt

Lets say I have written a very simple program in an operating system which supports UI. My program looks like below:-

```
#include <os_specific_ui.h>
int main()
{
 // Create a button using os specific API
 object my_button = add_button("I am a button"); 

 // Register for a mouse down call back on that button
 mouse_down_handler = register_mouse_down_cb(my_button, func_to_be_called_on_mouse_down);

 // do something... 
 // have a lot of functions which keep calling each other for a long period of time
}

void func_to_be_called_on_mouse_down(void)
{
 print("my_button got clicked");
}
```

The program is clearly a single threaded program. When I run it, it keeps on doing something. In the mean time if there is a mouse down event, then callback registered for it will get hit and start executing.

I want to know how can another process (which handles mouse movements) can call a function in my process? And what happens to the state of my process when such a callback is hit. I mean my program was doing something when callback was hit. So it just stops doing that and starts executing callback or what? And what after the callback function finishes executing? Does my program go back to do whatever it was doing before callback was hit?

Comment: The other process calls something in the operating system or window system that tells it to trigger an event in your window. That causes your program to react to the event just as if you'd actually clicked on the mouse button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much all GUI programs run some form of [event/main loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). That is, as the last part in main() it enters a loop, which reads events from the OS, and dispatches those events to your callback handlers and performs other tasks to realize the GUI.

i.e. the code you have in `// have a lot of functions which  keep calling each other` just isn't possible unless you do that in a separate thread. Your own execution flow isn't stopped and taken over by some other process.

A GUI program is more or less done like this:

```
#include <os_specific_ui.h>
void func_to_be_called_on_mouse_down(void)
{
 print("my_button got clicked");
}
int main()
{
 // Create a button using os specific API
 object my_button = add_button("I am a button"); 

 // Register for a mouse down call back on that button
 mouse_down_handler = register_mouse_down_cb(my_button, func_to_be_called_on_mouse_down);

    for (;;) {
       Event e 
       read_event_from_OS(&e);
       handle_event(&e);
    }
}
```

Where `read_event_from_OS()` fetches mouse/keyboard/redraw/etc. events from the operating system, and `handle_event()` figures out what to do with that event, such as redraw a window, or call one of the callback functions that your program has registered.

If the OS you're working on does things differently, you'll have to tell us more about it